# Correct plurals in a sentence

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, plural-forms

I am trying to figure out what is the proper plural for this sentence.

> What a difference seven years make!

OR

> What a difference seven years makes!

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Both forms will be heard, the singular, "seven years makes", I think a little more often than the plural. With the singular, the time period is understood to be a single contiguous length of time of a certain length, rather than multiple individual years.

Comment: There's hardly anything to add to this. However, much depends on how the seven years are rendered, either individually or as a single time line. I would often stick to the plural, since every year can be unique.

Comment: Time is typically a contiguous period, and it is here 'equated' to a singular 'difference', so the singular 'makes' is indicated.  We do the same with most measurements, since they are contiguous: 'seven feet *is* too long', 'seven liters *is* enough', etc.